# Typescript with Mongoose EXEC() function async/await

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I am trying to use Typescript with Express and Mongoose. So far the result has been amazing. I am however stuck at a very minor part.

**Premise: I am executing a Mongoose Query using EXEC()**

```
let result = await UserModel.User.find().exec();
```

I have to use the async / await as there is some processing after this line and I want to avoid callbacks throughout

**Problem**

I need to get the **{err, data}**  from the result object returned by the query. However currently it simply holds the entire data and I am not able to perform the error handling

So need a way to get the mongoose error description when I use **async/await**

Comment: Did you promisify this method : UserModel.User.find().exec(); . Doesnt this return a callback ??

Comment: Am avoiding the callback by using async and await

Answer (score 4):

Error handling using `async/await` is done by using `try/catch`:

```
try {
  let result = await UserModel.User.find().exec();
  ...
} catch(err) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the library await-to-js

Example:

const to = require(‘await-to-js’).default

const [err, result] = await to(func())
if (err) throw err

...